# "No available frame for creating stroke" what does this error actually mean?

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil

When I try to draw a stroke with grease pencil, I get this error:

[image]

I know I can fix it by turning on auto keying. My question isn't how to "fix" it, but what this error exactly means. Why do I need a keyframe to use grease pencil? Why can't I create a stroke like I create an object? What's actually stored in this keyframe?